# Grid net contour/outline QGIS

Tags: qgis, contour, grids-graticules

How to make a contour/outline of grid net polygon? Just need a thick boundary of the grid net to make the result more "beautiful".

I tried to do it somehow in symbology, but unsuccessfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you read [QGIS 3.4 Documentation | 3.2. Lesson: Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html) or [QGIS 2.8 Documentation | 3.2. Lesson: Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html) carefully?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, I did, but I'm probably too stupid. I have hex grid net with graduated symbology. I have absolutely no idea, how to draw the outline boundary.

Comment: There is nothing to do to with "stupid". Can you show us how do your polygons look like, please? Can you attach a print screen etc.?

Comment: Sure, here is small sample.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275159/symbology-different-ways-to-display-categorised-data-qgis-2-16/276178#276178

Comment: Thank you for a hint, @JGH, a Virtual Layer magician

Answer (score 2):

1. In case if you want each cell to be "Beautiful"

   Right click on your polygon shapefile and then `Properties -> Style -> Outline / Outline width`

   *Fill*: transparent and then apply customization for your polygon outline parameters.

[image: Styling_polygons]

2. If you want only the general contour of your cells to be "Beautiful", i.e. your cells have to have a common outline on the edge. Then follow the next procedure

   `Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Dissolve -> Dissolve all (do not use fields)`
   and then apply exactly the same actions as in Step 1.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS 2.8 Documentation | 3.2. Lesson: Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html)
- [QGIS 3.4 Documentation | 3.2. Lesson: Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html)
- [Basic Editing Geoprocessing Tools in QGIS | G. Dissolve](https://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks! But still there is something wrong... as you can see in the sample, there is not just a general outline, but some strange outlines inside the polygon.

Comment: Is it the result of your `"Dissolve"` activity?

Comment: Yes, it is the "Dissolve" result.

Comment: Apply it once again

Comment: Interesting, when I applied "Dissolve" again, the result was "nothing"... If I zoomed to layer, it was empty.