# How to create border around multiple polygons

Tags: qgis, borders

Spent hours on a search. No luck. I need to create a border around selected adjacent polygons. Concave Hull and Convex Hull don't give the desired results. It seems to be a simple request. The problem is when you deal with thousands of them. Please see before and after image attached.[image]

Comment: What about dissolve?

Comment: Followed by "Boundary" if the aim is to get a line, not polygon.

Comment: Here is a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276178/84870) using a virtual layer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it only for visualization purposes, you can use the first soution. Below you find a second solution that works for visualization purpose as well as in the case you want to create actual geometries (polygon or line):

**Solution 1:**

1. Duplicate the layer
2. Set the layer style to `Inverted polygons` > `Simple line`
3. Check the box next to `Merge polygons before rendering (slow)`

*Screenshot: yellow - original polygon layer; blue: duplicated layer:*
[image]

**Solution 2:**

You can use QGIS expressions to create a buffer around the outer boundary of the polygons. You can use either `Geometry generator` or `Geometry by Expression` ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with the following expression (replace `'my_layer'` with the name of your layer and adapt the size of the buffer - `800` in my example). You get a polygon - if you want to get a line instead, look to version B below:

```
difference( 
    buffer ( 
        aggregate( 
            'my_layer', 
            'collect', 
            $geometry
        ), 
    800),
    aggregate( 
            'my_layer', 
            'collect', 
            $geometry
        )
)
```

*Screenshot: demonstrating the solution using Geometry generator:*
[image]

**Version B**

To get a line instead of a polygon, simply add a `boundary ()` function and set the buffer value to something close to `0` (in my case: `1`):

[image]